# how to start a program using a windows service?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, service, exe

I created a windows service in c++ using visual studios and now I want the service to run an exe file. The service is set to start every time the computer starts

i know i need to use code to locate the path of the exe like `C:\MyDirectory\MyFile.exe` but how to I actually run the file from the service?

i read about the process start method [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) but i am not sure how to use it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use createprocess function in your service to run an exe.

```
TCHAR* path = L"C:\\MyDirectory\\MyFile.exe";

STARTUPINFO info;
PROCESS_INFORMATION processInfo;

ZeroMemory( &info, sizeof(info) );
info.cb = sizeof(info);
ZeroMemory( &processInfo, sizeof(processInfo) );


if (CreateProcess(path, NULL, NULL, NULL, TRUE, 0, NULL, NULL, &info, &processInfo))
{
    ::WaitForSingleObject(processInfo.hProcess, INFINITE);
    CloseHandle(processInfo.hProcess);
    CloseHandle(processInfo.hThread);
}
```

Comment: thanks for the code but i am getting some compile errors with it. is that code not complete or do i need to add header files?

Comment: @user2295419  Include #include <windows.h>.  Refer the link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682512(VS.85).aspx

Comment: i added this code: LPCWSTR path ="C:\\MyDirectory\\MyFile.exe";
 LPWSTR cmd = "something";

Comment: but i get these errors: error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'const char [26]' to 'LPCWSTR' 
error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'const char [10]' to 'LPWSTR'

Comment: @user2295419 added datatypes in example . I'm able to compile it.

Comment: thanks it does compile now but the code isn't starting the program for me when i start the service

Comment: I've few questions. a) Are you able to see that process in taskmanager? The process you are trying to launch is a backend or UI. If UI you have to enable "Allow service to interact with desktop" in your service property(In services list select your service, goto properties, goto logon tab and enable checkbox "allow services to interact with desktop"     c) Which OS are you trying?

Comment: no i can't see the process in taskmanager. i set the service to interact with desktop but that didn't work either. I'm using windows 7

Comment: i tested my code in a normal console application and it works but it doesn't work when i put the code into the service program

Comment: can't debug a service program so i created a log file to see if its executing all the lines. the log file was empty so i think the problem is my service isn't running the function i put this code into

Comment: Windows 7 has lot of security issue related to UAC(user access control) .You may not have sufficient access to create logfile and do write operation. Let me create sample service and I'll come back to you  sometime later.

Comment: @shivakumarthe problem isn't with the log file. its the code.

Comment: @shivakumarthe problem still isn't solved. i don't know why it works perfectly in a console application but not in my service program